# Jenkins with subversion plugin and AD athentication

Tags: svn, jenkins, active-directory, visualsvn-server

I'm configuring a Jenkins instance installed as a windows service. In order to download the source code, I would like to use the subversion plugin, but I'm getting an authentication error when I add the credentials (user name/password). The same user can get the code using svn command line.

The system configuration:

- Windows 2008 R2 64
- Jenkins 1.609
- Vusual SVN, configured to authenticate with active directory

Error

```
Passing user name AD\jenkins and password you entered
Failed to authenticate: svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '/svn/URL': 401 Authorization Required (https://svn.domain)
FAILED: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/URL failed
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/URL failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:388)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:707)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:627)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:102)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1020)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:99)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.postCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1950)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doPostCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1895)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor786.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/URL failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication failed for https://svn.domain/svn/URL
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:47)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:41)
    at hudson.scm.UserProvidedCredential$AuthenticationManagerImpl.getNextAuthentication(UserProvidedCredential.java:224)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:697)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:382)
    ... 89 more
```